# Проблема с запуском и пакетами OpenCV python. Debian

Tags: python, linux, debian, opencv

Установил основные библиотеки:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
pip3 install numpy opencv-python
```

Раньше всё работало, но с переустановкой ОС (Debian) начала вылазить ошибка:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Код использовал тестовый (чтобы просто проверить работу):

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("camera", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте попробуем разобраться. Есть у меня мысль, что проблема возникает из-за того, что OpenCV не может использовать Qt. Поставьте зависимости для поддержки Qt и X11:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0
sudo apt-get install libqt5x11extras5
```

После установки попробуйте запустить свой код. Если проблема не ушла, едем дальше:

```
sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-0
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev
```

Потом если что, попробуйте переустановить OpenCV:

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Если все решения не помогают, попробуйте поставить другую версию OpenCV:

```
pip3 install opencv-python==4.5.1.48
```

**UPDATE**

Проверьте переменную окружения DISPLAY с помощью команды

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

Обычно она должна иметь значение `:0` или `:1`.
Если у вас переменная DISPLAY не установлена, выполните следующую команду для установки значения по умолчанию:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

**UPDATE 2**

Такая ошибка может возникнуть при подключении через SSH, если у системы отключен монитор или если сессия SSH не настроена на передачу графического интерфейса. Что можно сделать:

1. Ставим на локальном компьютере X сервер. Если у вас Windows, можно воспользоваться `VcXsrv` или `Xming`. Если вы используете macOS, можно установить `XQuartz`.
2. Запускаете X сервер.
3. Подключитесь к серваку с помощью SSH с опцией `-X` или `-Y`, чтобы включить проброс X11:

   ```
    ssh -X username@remote_host
   ```

Опция -X включает проброс X11 с проверкой доступа, а опция -Y включает проброс с расширенными возможностями, не уверен, что оно вам надо, но всё же.

4. Выше уже писал, после подключения через SSH с опцией `-X` или `-Y`, убедитесь, что переменная окружения `DISPLAY` установлена на удаленной машине. В этот раз, она может выдать что-то типа: `localhost:1`

Ну и теперь, когда вы подключены через SSH с включенным X11, ваш код должен работать без проблем, и графический интерфейс будет отображаться на вашем локальном компьютере.

Comment: Ничего не помогло :((

root@orangepi3-lts:/home/orangepi/drone# python3 test.py
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Aborted

Comment: о, знаю, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Тоже не помогло. А может быть такое из-за того, что я запускаю программу по ssh, а не через апельсинку напрямую? Сейчас проверю

Comment: Да :/. Напрямую с системы всё прекрасно запустилось, а вот по ssh не хотело. Есть вопрос, может ли возникнуть такая ошибка, если у системы отключен монитор?

Comment: Дополнил Х сервером

Comment: Если у системы отключен монитор, вам все равно нужно выполнить эти шаги, чтобы отображать графический интерфейс на локальной машине через SSH

Comment: Спасибо большое!